# Install PHP 5.4.1 in centos6.2

Tags: php, centos

In centos6.2 default is php 5.3.3.
But i want install php 5.4.1.
Can you help me?
How do php5.4.1 install in centos6.2?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum install php54w
```

See [this](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php54/) for more info.

Comment: i had done rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum install php54w but show phpinfo() still php 5.3.3

Comment: @user1497597 Did you uninstall PHP 5.3.3 before you installed 5.4?

Comment: i run: yum remove php , affter install php5.4 with 2 raw command that, result show phpinfo() only show code (don't load)

Comment: @user1497597 You have to restart Apache: `service httpd restart` or whatever webserver do you use.

Comment: yes , i had restart computer and run service httpd restart but not load

Comment: i install : yum install php-devel and restart service , show page phpinfo() ok but it still show 5.3.3

Comment: @user1497597 It's `php54w-devel`. I have no idea why it's not working, try with other package.

Comment: ok thanks you very much, i had yum remove php and yum remove php-*, after install php54 had ok.

Comment: can I install xcache on php54w ?

Answer (score 6):

1. you must `yum remove php-common` that will remove php from your server.
2. then `php -v` to make sure there is no php
3. finally `rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm` followed by `yum install php54w`
4. and ideally you would want to install php54w-fpm too